# VB.net Proxy doesn't change after first HttpWebRequest

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, proxy, httpwebrequest

I have a public function to get the pagesource of web URLs. Here is the function.

```
Public Function gethtml(ByVal id As Integer)
Try
                ListView1.Items(id).SubItems(6).Text = "Downloading HTML..."
                Dim Response3 As HttpWebResponse
                Dim pagesource3 As String
                Dim datastream As Stream
                Dim postdata As String = ""
                Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postdata)
                Dim Request3 As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://mysite.com/ip.php")
                Request3.Referer = "http://google.com/"
                Request3.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
                Request3.KeepAlive = True
                Request3.Timeout = "5000"
                Request3.AllowAutoRedirect = True
                If useproxycheckbox.Checked = True Then
                    Dim words As String() = ListView1.Items(id).SubItems(9).Text.Split(New Char() {":"c})
                    Request3.Proxy = New WebProxy(words(0).ToString & ":" & words(1).ToString)
                    Request3.UseDefaultCredentials = False
                    Request3.Proxy.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(words(2).ToString, words(3).ToString)
                End If
                Request3.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.43 Safari/537.31"
                Request3.CookieContainer = CC
                Request3.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get
                Request3.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                Response3 = Request3.GetResponse()
                Dim Stream3 As New StreamReader(Response3.GetResponseStream())
                pagesource3 = Stream3.ReadToEnd()
                Response3.Close()
                Stream3.Close()
                ListView1.Items(id).SubItems(4).Text = pagesource3

Catch e1 As ProtocolViolationException
    recheck(id)
    ListView1.Items(id).SubItems(6).Text = "Error1"
Catch e2 As WebException
    recheck(id)
    ListView1.Items(id).SubItems(6).Text = "Error2"

End Try
End Function
```

The problem is it works fine with first call like

```
gethtml(0)
```

But after that, it doesn't use the proxy I provide to it. it simply uses the same proxy used in the 1st request. I'm calling this function using a thread because if I use this on main thread I'll freeze the UI. What I'm doing wrong? I'm a noob in VB.net

Thanks.

UPDATE: Just found that this problem only occurs with proxies having USERNAME:PASSWORD basic authentication. Help me!

Comment: Looking at all that code makes me want to use [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) more ;)

Comment: :) mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm